# Normality and Field Extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let M : L : K be finite field extensions. When M is not normal over K, give four
examples to show that this gives no information about the normality of M over L or
of L over K. What are the possibilities if M is normal over K?

Comment: Can you give just *any* example of a normal and a not normal extension?

Comment: @Hagen so $A=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/2})$ is a splitting field for $a(x)=x^2 - 2$ because all roots of $a$ are in $A$ and since $a(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ I know that $A$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Alternatively, let $B=\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$ and $b(x)=x^3 - 2$ then not all roots of $b$ are in $B$ so $B$ is not a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Now for the first part of the problem you might take $M=\mathbb Q(2^{1/3})$, $K=\mathbb Q$ and cheat a little by letting $L=M$ or $L=K$, respectively. For the second part, waht can you sa about $M:L$ if $M:K$ is normal?

Comment: Given that extensions of finite fields are always normal, I judged that for the OP *finite* only refers to the extension as opposed to *field*, so I removed the *finite-fields* tag.

Answer (score 3):

The question being 4 months old, I guess it's safe to assume the homework assignment was due a while ago, so we can give answers.

In all cases, take $K={\bf Q}$.

Let $M={\bf Q}(2^{1/16})$, so $M$ is not normal over $K$.

Take $L_1={\bf Q}(2^{1/8})$, $L_2={\bf Q}(2^{1/4})$, $L_3={\bf Q}(2^{1/2})$.

Then:
$M/L_1$ is normal, $L_1/K$ is not.
$M/L_2$ is not normal, neither is $L_2/K$.
$M/L_3$ is not normal, but $L_3/K$ is. 
$L_2/K$ is not normal, but $L_2/L_3$ and $L_3/K$ both are.

Still with $K={\bf Q}$:

If $M/K$ is normal, then $M/L$ is normal, but $L/K$ could go either way. E.g., if $M={\bf Q}(\root4\of2,i)$, then $L_1={\bf Q}(\root4\of2)$ is not normal over $K$, but $L_2={\bf Q}(i)$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple examples.  Let $\mathbb{F}$ have characteristic $p$ and consider

1. $\mathbb{F}_p(x):\mathbb{F}_p(x^p):\mathbb{F}$,
2. $\mathbb{F}_p(x,\alpha):\mathbb{F}_p(x):\mathbb{F}(x^p)$

where $\alpha$ is algebraic.